# Install curl from tarball , windows

Tags: curl

I am trying to install older version of curl found here : https://curl.haxx.se/download/. I see .zip file, but when I unzip I dont find .exe file. How do I build curl.exe from this?

Comment: go to the `curl-x.xx.x./winbuild` directory, then follow the instructions described in `BUILD.WINDOWS.txt`.

Comment: I dont find winbuild folder in the unzipped folder of curl-x.xx.x.